# A question for my Case Study is confusing me. (JSON related)

Tags: python, json, filter, key

So i have a case study for an internship and it has the question
Retrieve **JSON Data** and display data following source : https://workwithus.pinpointhq.com/jobs.json
with the filter: workplace_type_text = Fully remote
I understand that workplace_type_text is the key and i should use it for the filtering. But the JSON file is not like the usual files that are structured in a way that it's easy to retrieve the data from.
What should i do?

```
import json

with open('case_study.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)  # Check the structure and content of the loaded JSON data

filtered_data = [item for item in data if item['workplace_type_text'] == 'Fully remote']

for item in filtered_data:
    print(item['name'], item['price'])
```

I've tried that code but that only prints the entirety of the file and shows a **TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'** for the `filtered_data = [item for item in data if item['workplace_type_text'] == 'Fully remote']`

So i changed it to

```
import json

with open('case_study.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

filtered_data = [item for item in data if 'workplace_type_text' in item and item['workplace_type_text'] == 'Fully remote']

print(filtered_data)  # Check the contents of the filtered_data list

for item in filtered_data:
    print(item['name'], item['price'])
```

now it only prints out [] and nothing else

trying to check if the key is correct with

```
import json

with open('case_study.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data.keys())
```

also doesn't print anything. I'm lost did i skip a step? Thank you.

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide the structure of the input json (maybe anonymized)

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve info from your "case_study.json" you can easily exploit **pandas** to create a DataFrame from the 'data' object in your JSON file.
Then you can filter data based on the 'workplace_type_text' column, if you desire.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('case_study.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])

filtered_df = df[df['workplace_type_text'] == 'Fully remote']

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

print(filtered_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` json object is a dictionary, you can see it by:

```
type(data)
# dict
```

`data` has only one key named `'data'`:

```
data.keys()
# dict_keys(['data'])
```

so you're going to have to filter `data['data']` by values.

To extract the desired items use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: x['workplace_type_text'] == 'Fully remote', data['data']))
```

or else a simple list comprehension:

```
result = [job for job in data['data'] if job['workplace_type_text'] == 'Fully remote']
```

Visualize result for instance:

```
[(job['title'], job['workplace_type_text']) for job in result] 
# [('Senior Sales Account Executive ', 'Fully remote'),
#  ('Senior Software Developer', 'Fully remote'),
#  ('Customer Success Manager', 'Fully remote'),
#  ('Senior Sales Account Executive ', 'Fully remote'),
#  ('Customer Success Manager', 'Fully remote'),
#  ('Community Marketing Manager', 'Fully remote'),
#  ('Partnerships Marketing Manager', 'Fully remote'),
#  ('Head of Support Engineering (Rails)', 'Fully remote'),
#  ('Head of Support Engineering (Rails)', 'Fully remote'),
#  ('Demand Generation Manager', 'Fully remote'),
#  ('Partnerships Marketing Manager', 'Fully remote')]
```